# Initial Object Reference for OLE Automation Object with constructor

Tags: c++, com, ole

I'm trying to interface a library that exports an Automation compatible interface via a .TLB.

The TLB lists `function`s inside the interfaces to retrieve object references; the .TLH includes these as nonstatic member functions, which makes it difficult for me to call them without an object reference; thus, I have a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem here.

What is the correct way to invoke `function`s from C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `#import` on the .tlb file, then use `CreateInstance()` method of an appropriate smart pointer type to instantiate the object, then just call member functions.

Something like this (error handling omitted):

```
 #import ThatTlbFile.tlb

 //at some point in your code you have to init COM
 CoInitialize(0);

 // once COM is initialized
 IInterfaceOfInterestPtr object;
 // this will ask COM to instantiate an object    
 object.CreateInstance( __uuidof( ComClassOfInterest ) );
 object->CallMethod();
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for (I know this bit), but apparently I've made a mistake in assuming that this function was a constructor -- rather, the interface I was looking at has a method for opening related objects, and as no registered class implements the interface, I assumed that these were ctor functions. I've found the root object for talking to the component now, which is registered and has factory methods for the object I need.